# Image registration algorithms for images with varying distances

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have two cameras side by side. I'd like to register two images taken from each camera. I will assume there won't be any rotational differences between cameras, that is, there will be only translation factor for the images.

I think global transformation will not work for this issue since changes of distances between two images for the closer objects are significantly higher. What should I do in this case? I tried to read some papers but I am not sure which one is the perfect match for me. Do you have any suggestions such as "read this paper", "apply this algorithm", "know this and that" etc.

The project that I'm working on is real-time and image registration will be implemented in the GPU.

Comment: What do you mean by "global transformation will not work?"

Comment: I mean that applying a single transformation to whole image will not work solely.

Comment: Why do you need the registration? If you are trying to get the distance map you should look at calculating the disparity. For a simple intro on the topic look at http://www.epixea.com/research/multi-view-coding-thesisse13.html.

Comment: Two cameras take ldr frames at different exposures. I try to align them so that I can generate one hdr frame.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not assume such constraints like just translational differences. You will have inaccuracies and you will not spare any effort.

Second, a global transformation (I assume you mean a linear transformation i.e. a homography applied to your images) will only work if you have pictures of completely planar surfaces, so you're right, it won't work. You will need a non-rigid image registration. Further, I hope the distance between these two cameras is not too far. Due to [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax), you may have artifacts.

I would recommend to google for terms like "non-rigit image registration for hdr", "stack-based hdr" or "image registration for hdr". You'll find a lot.

However I found this nice overview [paper](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~psen/Papers/Gallo16_StackBasedHDR.pdf). I think it is a good start.

Comment: I will fix the positions of two cameras and they won't be far from each other. In fact, they will almost touch each other. However, I think there will be parallax(may be too small) even for this case, right? Should I implement a stereo matching algorithm? The problem for now is that I want to match every pixel from the left frame with the pixels from the right frame(without considering the frames are taken at different exposures)